# How to set up routing properly in a dynamically loaded Angular module?

Tags: angular, routes

I have an app with a router outlet, in which I want to lazy-load modules with their own sub-routes.

This should give the routes:

```
/
/lazy1/child1
/lazy1/child2
```

in the root app module, I define some routes that will lazy-load the child module

```
export const routes: Routes = [
  {path:'', component: HelloComponent},
  {path: 'lazy1', loadChildren: () => import('./lazy1-module/index').then(mod => mod.Lazy1Module)}
];
```

and in the Lazy1Module, the following routes

```
const routes: Routes = [
 {path: 'child1', component: Child1Component},
 {path: 'child2', component: Child2Component},
 {path: '**', redirectTo: 'child1'}
];
```

which i add with RouterModule.forChild(routes) as normal.

This seems to work fine, and when I go to /lazy1/child1 this resolves fine.

However, when i try to navigate between the childs i bump into trouble.
As the lazy-loaded module in it self should not know or care for routes outside itself, I would assume that I could navigate from child1 to child2 using

```
this.router.navigate(["child2"]);
```

This results in a 'route not found' error.

I can make it work by adding

```
this.router.navigate(["child2"], { relativeTo: this.route.parent });
```

But this seems wrong. also "../child2" does not work.

Adding logging to the router, it seems that it adds a "/" in front of the route and starts to resolve it from root also disregarding any dots.

I'm using Angular 8.2.14

Stackblitz example here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bqdchr

Comment: `this.router.navigate(['/lazy/child2']);`

Comment: Thanx for the comment, however I'm trying not to use absolute paths as the lazy-loaded module may be loaded in different contexts and not necessarily has 'lazy' as parent.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this [stackblitz:](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nested-routing-with-modules-with-bootstrap?embed=1&file=src/index.html)

I think it's because your lazy routes don't know it's own root so you need to add:

```
path:'', component: LazyComponent, children: [
  { path: 'child1', component: Child1Component },
  { path: 'child2', component: Child2Component }
]
```

Comment: I looked at the stackblitz, and it has a second router-outlet in the LazyComponent, which I do not have. I see how this can solve my problem, but I was hoping not to have another layer just because.

Comment: ah i see what you mean now.

Answer (score 0):

You can navigate by absolute or relative paths.

```
this.router.navigate(['child2']);
```

is using an absolute path (because there is no `relativeTo` flag) and navigates to `/child2`.
You have no route defined for `/child2` but for `/lazy1/child2`.

The console error is telling you that:

> Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'child2'

It would work if you would rewrite it to:

```
this.router.navigate(['lazy1', 'child2']);
```

Your working example is using a relative path:

```
this.router.navigate(["child2"], { relativeTo: this.route.parent });
```

The parent of you current route is `lazy`. From there you're navigating to `child2` which is a valid route (`/lazy/child2`).

See https://angular.io/api/router/Router#navigate for more information.
The following could also be interesting: https://angular.io/guide/router#router-links

Comment: Thanx Steven, this is a good write-up of what I have found also. Would you then agree or disagree with me that this behaviour is strange? I would assume navigating to 'child2' (not '/child2') would navigate to either a sibling or sub route, not a root child. My use-case is to try and dynamically load a module, which could be either attached at root (in which case it works) or under a context like in the example.

Answer (score 0):

Your routes of lazy as:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {path:'',children:[
    {path: 'child1', component: Child1Component},
    {path: 'child2', component: Child2Component}
  ]},
 {path: '**', redirectTo: 'child1'}
];
```

Then, you can do

```
this.router.navigate(["child2"], { relativeTo: this.route.parent });
//or
this.router.navigate(["../child2"],{ relativeTo: this.route});
```

Comment: Did you try this? It seems to me it makes no difference, and I still have to add the relativeTo property. I really appreciate your efforts though :) I'm really struggeling to make sense of what should be the expected default behaviour. To me it should not be necessary to add a relativeTo property as the default should be the active routes parent. Should I file a bug with the Angular team, or does it actually make sense as is somehow?

Comment: your forked stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wzegos?file=src%2Fapp%2Flazy-module%2Fchild1%2Fchild1.component.ts